# Android: How to detect when a disabled Checkbox is touched?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I require that sometimes my Checkboxes in a `ListView` are not tickable. I'm using `setEnabled(false)`.

Is there anyway to fire a toast message when the user still clicks on the disabled `Checkbox`?

I am also using a custom `ArrayAdapter` overriding the `getView` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :) using a helper class that extends `CheckBox` and overrides `onTouchEvent`, kind of like:

```
public class DisabledTouchableCheckbox extends CheckBox {

    public DisabledTouchableCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if ((!isEnabled()) && (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) 
            showToast();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void showToast() {
            ... show your toast
    }

}
```

Then in your XML's you have to change `<CheckBox>` for `<com.YOURPACKAGE.DisabledTouchableCheckBox>`

Comment: This might be a feasible solution, I hope this gets looked at as a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement this tomorrow.

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's a reason they call it **disabled**.

You could create a custom Checkbox using the same assets, but I guess that's just wasting time. User's will know the checkbox is disabled, because disabled widgets are shown in 30% alpha.